# How to install EduBOSS linux theme into ubuntu unity?

Tags: unity, themes

I have [EduBOSS](https://www.bosslinux.in/eduboss) 4.0 Linux DVD. I was install EduBOSS but its lot of problems I faced. So I decide use Ubuntu only. But I want EduBOSS theme into Ubuntu.
Please gives answers for off-line as well on-line EduBOSS theme installation for Ubuntu Unity.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Is it possible to install that theme from BOSS Linux DVD?

Comment: I can tell you that the OS uses the GNOME desktop environment. However, the icon theme appears to be original.

Comment: This icon theme resembles what EduBOSS has: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Boston?content=171306

Comment: We wouldn't be able to help you figure out how to get the icon theme from an installer, since we don't know how it works.

Comment: @Zacharee1 so deb pkg in only option for it....

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: From the look of it's website, the icon theme seems to be Faenza based.

Comment: @Zacharee1 some thing unity+gnome http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/unity-gnome?content=175555

Comment: Why don't you just install GNOME DE?

Comment: @Zacharee1 if I install Gnome DE then can I able to Unity also if yes then I really install GNOME DE.

Comment: Why do you still want to use Unity?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Because I love unity and its user friendly. I use it from 2 years.

Comment: @MadhavNikam But you said you want your OS to look exactly like GNOME.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37285/discussion-between-madhav-nikam-and-zacharee1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EduBOSS 4.0 uses the GNOME Desktop Environment. If you want something resembling EduBOSS, install GNOME and use it instead of Unity. As for the icons, you'll have to find something you like. The icon theme on EduBOSS appears to be original.

To install and use GNOME on your computer:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.
2. Once that installs, log out.
3. Click the gear icon to the right of the `Password` section.
4. Select the `Ubuntu GNOME` option and log in.

You will now have a desktop that looks like EduBOSS.